# What is this control which is in Windows 10 Store App?

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

[image]

How to create this control in Windows 10 Universal App? Please help. Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the Pivot control, which was previously available only for Windows Phone, and is now also available for the universal device family. The Pivot control provides adaptive behavior based on the screen size and input type.

This [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPivot) shows how to implement this control. You can style it in different ways - the option you are looking for would be scenario 1 from the code sample. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.I have tested pivot element in universal app, it is working fine. But how can I place grid (which contains image, title) in the header part, so that when user clicks it has to take the user to that product ? And also I don't require pivot body, just it has to show list of clickable products with small description.